# Toggle view inside a cell row?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with some contents. The cells have their own UITableViewCell class that has two UIView and a UILabel properties. When the user taps a cell, one of the views changes it's color. But if I want to return the previous color, it doesn't happen.

I tried with custom BOOL variable, with some methods inside the UITableViewCell class, everything - no success.

(Note: I tried with the UITableViewCellAccessoryType accessory (I don't want cell accessory, I just tried it) and it worked......)

So, how can I toggle a view/label/anything inside a cell? Thank you.

p.s. I can show you code, but it seems more theoretical question......

Comment: Show the code you have tried. What is the difference between when you say it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: I will upload some code in Github, if that's okay.

Comment: It's best to add the relevant code directly to the question (so that there is a record of it and it's accurate compared to the rest of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you override `setSelected:` in your table view cell subclass and change to color there (depending on the selected state.

Like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
  [super setSelected:selected];

  if (selected) {
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 } else {
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 }
}
```

Comment: `setSelected:` returns only TRUE. I'm new to Obj-c, so if you please explain how to override the method.... I will be thankful :)

Comment: In your UITableViewCell subclass define a - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {} method. Inside check for the selected state and determine what color to set based on the value of the selected parameter.